# how to write an embed file to disk?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

My goal is to write embed resources to file

```
[Embed(source="Embed/viewer.js", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
private var viewer_js:Class;

[Embed(source="Embed/viewer2.js", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
private var viewer2_js:Class;


private function writeAssetToFile(embed:Class, targetFileName:String):void {
    var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath(targetFileName);
    var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fs.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);

    fs.writeBytes(embed as ByteArray); // error here
    fs.close(); 
}
```

ex:

```
 writeAssetToFile(viewer_js,"viewer.js");
```

fs.writeBytes(embed as ByteArray); is the line that creates problem.

regards

Comment: Since your getting an error, it would be helpful if you included it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to write an instance of a class, like this:

```
private function writeAssetToFile(embed:Class, targetFileName:String):void {
    var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath(targetFileName);
    var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fs.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
    fs.writeBytes(new embed() as ByteArray); // here, should fix
    fs.close(); 
}
```

The trick is, anything embedded as `application/octet-stream` is instantiated as a `ByteArray` descendant, so you don't need to do anything more.